# Unable to push changes to remote repository in Git

Tags: git, version-control, push, remote-repository

I am encountering an issue while trying to push changes to a remote repository in Git. The push command gets stuck and doesn't complete, preventing me from updating the remote repository with my local changes

I have attempted to push the changes using the following command:

```
[kuroshite@kajukatli schoolproject23]$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 51, done.
Counting objects: 100% (51/51), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (43/43), done.
Writing objects: 100% (45/45), 46.40 MiB | 3.54 MiB/s, done.
Total 45 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
```

I expected the push operation to complete successfully, updating the remote repository with my local commits. However, the command hangs after displaying progress information and doesn't proceed any further.

Comment: Are you using a proxy?